How to compare 2 separate effective potentials where the orders of $\phi$ differ?
In S. Coleman's Fate Of the False Vacuum, he determines that in the thin-wall approximation, where we take $\epsilon$, or the difference between the 2 vacua in vacuum decay to be small, a potential of the form: $$\tag 1 U = \frac{\lambda}{8} \left( \phi^2 - \frac{\mu^2}{\lambda}\right)^2 + \frac{\epsilon}{2a}(\phi - a)$$ Has Euclidean action: $$B = \frac{\pi^2 \mu^{12}}{6 \epsilon^3\lambda^4}$$
Using the parameterisation used initially in Towards The Theory Of The Electroweak Phase Transition, by Dine, Leigh et.al I have a function that should determine the Euclidean action for a potential of the form: $$ \tag 2 U = \frac{M^2(T)}{2} \phi^2 -ET \phi^3 + \frac{\lambda_0}{4} \phi^4$$
The thin-wall approximation should be equivalent to taking the asymmetric cubic term to be small. For a sanity check, and to make sure I have the scaling factors correct, I would like to do a direct comparison between these 2 potentials. However, as it is written currently I can not express $U_{Coleman}$ in the form of potential I can analyse, primarily because of the term in $\phi$; I can rescale to eliminate the scalar difference. How could I go about comparing these 2 results? Is there a clever substitution I could make that I'm not seeing?

As a start,- you can expand and regroup Coleman expression noticing that first brackets are in the form $(a^2-b^2)^2$, after doing it (lets assume for simplicity that $\phi \gg a$), we get :  $$ U = \frac 12 \left ( \frac{\mu^4}{4\lambda} + \frac{\epsilon \phi}{a} - \frac {\mu^2 \phi^2}{2} + \frac{\lambda \phi^4}{4} \right). $$  Second-order and fourth-order terms then matches (2) equation even terms, assuming cubic term small. Well, except some signs and new $\phi^0, \phi^1$ (constant and linear) terms which are missing in (2) equation. So maybe additional action/assumptions are needed.
